# How does entity_metadata_wrapper work with array?

Tags: nodes, theming, entities

This is my code to return value of fields in a content type called `library`

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
$variables['name']= $wrapper->field_library_book_name->value();
$variables['writer']= $wrapper->field_library_book_writer->value();     
$variables['detail']= $wrapper->field_library_book_detail->value();
$variables['photo']= $wrapper->field_library_photo->value();
```

it works right for name, writer and detail but for image it only prints **Array()**. this is the `var_dump()` output of this array:

```
array(13) {
  ["fid"] => string(3) "382"
  ["alt"]=> string(0) ""
  ["title"]=> string(0) ""
  ["width"]=> string(3) "145"
  ["height"]=> string(3) "194"
  ["uid"]=> string(2) "23"
  ["filename"]=> string(15) "n_471_1_img.png"
  ["uri"]=> string(43) "public://library_book_photo/n_471_1_img.png"
  ["filemime"]=> string(9) "image/png"
  ["filesize"]=> string(5) "40854"
  ["status"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1389166558"
  ["rdf_mapping"]=> array(0) { }
}
```

this is my question: how to output the image itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) will output the value as an img-tag. Is that what you are looking for?

```
$photo_field = $wrapper->field_library_photo->value();
$image = theme('image_style',
  array(
    'style_name' => 'large',
    'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
  )
);
```